# rubocop_todo / how to re-include specific files for rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formatting, rubocop, linter

Having the following part in rubocop_todo.yml

```
Metrics/AbcSize:
  Max: 749
```

What i'd like to do, would be to add specific files that would have to respect the default (in other words : 'every files can reach mega-high Metrics/AbcSize, but the ones i'd like to improve)

Tried the following :

```
Metrics/AbcSize:
  Max: 749
  Exclude:
    - app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb
```

But nothing happens. Using `Includes`, same

I feel like the problem should be taken with another approach; but still I'm a bit stuck

thx in advance

Comment: From a quick google, `Exclude` should be what you need... have you made sure that the file-path is relative to the rubocop.yml file (not your rails root)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish you could use formatting in comments... but yeah like Taryn East said, make sure your rubocop.yml is in the root. For comparison's sake, here's some lines from my file:

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - bin/**/*
    - db/*
    - spec/factories/**/*
    - tmp/**/*
    - vendor/**/*
```